# How to get a specific list item without going thru for-loop method?

Tags: java

Say, I have `List<String>` and it stored as "A", "B", "C", "D", "E". If I want to get item 3 result = "C". How can I do this without going thru for-loop method?

Comment: You can use while loop :D

Comment: just out of curiosity, how were you planning to do it with the for loop?

Comment: Why not use ArrayList<String>?

Comment: If this is something you will do frequently with your data, and you have control over how it's stored, then you ought to move away from a List as they are not designed for this usage case: use ArrayList<String> or a map with numeric keys with your strings as values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [List#get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method of list like :

```
myList.get(2);
```

Also note that the index is `0` based (So using `2` will return 3rd element)

Comment: You are always welcome! One advise if you like - always refer the docs you get plenty of information there

Comment: @lannyboy and if you're using an IDE the autocomplete options after the dot are often illuminating

Answer (score 6):

Use List's [get(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29)  method `//index - index of the element to return`

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

In your case use `listObj.get(2);` //return `"C"`.

Comment: I was looking for the link while you posted your answer :_(

Answer (score 2):

You can [get](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) the item from the list by the index number:

```
list.get(2); //it will return the third item in the list
```

Note that 0 is the first index item.

Answer (score 2):

If you were planning to use a `for`-loop,I guess that was because you didn't know at which index was "C" in your list ?.
If that's the case, then you can use `#indexOf(Object o)` method :

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("a");
al.add("b");
al.add("c");
System.out.println(al.get(al.indexOf("b")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");
    list.add("E");
    System.out.println(list.get(2));
```

**Array list index start form 0 as Arrays.**